# Dynamically change brush color vb.net, system.drawing.solidbrush is not available

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a database that has a color in it.  I want to take that color and apply it to dynamically generated buttons.  It seems the way to do this is using SolidBrush.  However - that's not defined.  I tried including system.drawing, but it's still not available....

```
        Dim newbutton As New Button 

        newbutton.Content = catArray(0, t)
        newbutton.Height = 50
        newbutton.Width = 175
        newbutton.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left
        newbutton.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top

        Dim Brsh As New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(readColor))

        newbutton.Margin = New Thickness(y, l, 0, 0)
        newbutton.Name = "cat" & catArray(2, t)

        AddHandler newbutton.Click, AddressOf catHandler


        grdCat.Children.Add(newbutton)
```

I tried adding System.Drawing as a reference to the project, but I get this error:

"A reference to "System.Drawing.dll could not be added.

The ActiveX type library c:\Windows\Microsoft.net\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Drawing.tlb was exported from a .net assembly and cannot be added as a reference.

Add a reference to the .net assembly instead."

I tried to "Add a reference to the .net assembly" and got the same error...

I'm sure this is something stupid - all i want to do is change a button color, which was super easy in winforms...

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: `System.Drawing.SolidBrush` is WinForms. Use `System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush` in WPF.

Comment: Thanks, Clemens!  That's exactly what I needed.  I appreciate your help!